# grabbing a file's extention for an if else statement

Tags: javascript

I know that if else statements are pretty straight forward.

```
if (a == b)
{do this}
else if (a > b)
{do that}
else {do yet some other thing}
```

However, I have a  long set of functions like so:

```
  var  entry, documentname, documentid, referenceID, callLogID, filePath, blob,cdr,fileObject;

$(document).ready(function() {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
});

var fileURL = "";
var imagePath = "";
function onDeviceReady() {  
    sessionStorage.platform = device.platform;
    var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
     $('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function()
        {   
            try {
 myuri = this.href;
filename = myuri.substr(30);

                if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
                }
                else {
                    window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemSuccess, onError);
                }

            }
            catch(err) {
                alert("ER - " + err.message);
            }

        }); 

        function onError(e) {
            alert("onError");
        };

        function onFileSystemSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry="";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }           
            entry.getDirectory("Carnets", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccess(dir) {
            dir.getDirectory("Fichiers_pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccess1, onGetDirectoryFail);
        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccess1(dir) {
            cdr = dir;
            dir.getFile(filename,{create:true, exclusive:false},gotFileEntry, errorHandler);
        };
        function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {  


                var uri = encodeURI(myuri);
                fileTransfer.download(uri,cdr.nativeURL+filename,
                    function(entry) {                       
                        openFile();
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("download error source " + error.source);
                        alert("download error target " + error.target);
                        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    true);              
        };

        function openFile() {
            /*alert("URL - " + cdr.nativeURL+filename); /* alerte 6*/
            cordova.plugins.fileOpener2.open(
                cdr.nativeURL+filename, 
                'application/pdf', 
                //'text/plain',
                { 
                    error : function(e) { 
                        alert('Error status: ' + e.status + ' - Error message: ' + e.message);
                    },
                    success : function () {                                    
                    }
                }
            );
        };
        function onFileSystemSuccessDelete(fileSystem) {
            var entry="";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }   
            entry.getDirectory("Carnets/Fichiers_pdf", {create: true, exclusive: false}, onGetDirectorySuccessDelete, onGetDirectoryFail);

        };
        function onGetDirectorySuccessDelete(dir) {
            dir.getFile(filename,{create: true, exclusive:false},gotFileEntryDelete, fail);                     
        };

        function gotFileEntryDelete(fileEntry) {
            fileEntry.remove();
            var uri = encodeURI("http://SERVER_IP:PORT/test.pdf");
                fileTransfer.download(uri,cdr.nativeURL+filename,
                    function(entry) {
                        console.log("download complete: " + entry.toURL());                     
                        openFile();
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        alert("download error source " + error.source);
                        alert("download error target " + error.target);
                        alert("upload error code" + error.code);
                        alert("error");
                    },
                    true);              
        };      

        function fail(error){
            alert("ec - " + error.code);
        };

        function  errorHandler(e) {
            var msg = '';
            switch (e.code) {
                case FileError.QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR:
                    msg = 'QUOTA_EXCEEDED_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
                    msg = 'NOT_FOUND_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.SECURITY_ERR:
                    msg = 'SECURITY_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR';
                    break;
                case FileError.INVALID_STATE_ERR:
                    msg = 'INVALID_STATE_ERR';
                    break;
                default:
                    msg = e.code;
                    break;
            };
            alert("Msg - " + msg);
        };

        function onGetDirectoryFail(error) {
            alert("onGetDirectoryFail");
        };

        $('#delete').click(ClearDirectory);

        function ClearDirectory() {
            alert("delete");
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory,onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
            }
            else {
                window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0,onFileSystemDirSuccess, fail);
            }        
        }
        function onFileSystemDirSuccess(fileSystem) {
            var entry = "";
            if (sessionStorage.platform.toLowerCase() == "android") {
                entry=fileSystem;
            }
            else {
                entry=fileSystem.root;
            }   
            entry.getDirectory("Cordova",{create : true, exclusive : false},
                function(entry) {
                    entry.removeRecursively(function() {
                        console.log("Remove Recursively Succeeded");
                    }, fail);
                }, getDirFail);
        }

        function getDirFail(error){
            alert("getDirFail - " + error.code);
        };

}
```

It works very well for all links ending in pdf.
Now I have href ending in .mp3
I would like to write something like this:

```
if ($('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function())
then {do this}
else if ($('a[href$=\\.mp3]').click(function())
then {do that}
```

Alas, it does not work.

I tried with

```
$('a[href$=\\.*]').click(function()
```

and then trying to get the file type thanks to this.href, but it does not work either.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need an `if` statement. The selector itself works like an `if` statement. Select the `a` elements _if_ their href ends with ...

Comment: That's not how JQuery works. Each `$(...)` is a completely separate thing. You don't need `if`/`else` statements for your use case.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to escape `.`. It's not a regular expression. You can simply write `$('a[href$=.pdf')`

Comment: I tried like this: 
$('a[href$=\\.pdf]').click(function())
then {do this};
$('a[href$=\\.mp3]').click(function())
then {do that}   
but it failled too :-/

Comment: You don't need `then`. What to do is inside the body of the function.

Comment: I will edit the question and write the full script...

Answer (score 0):

This code should work .

```
 $('a[href$=".mp3"]').click(function(){

    //do something 
    });

$('a[href$=".pdf"]').click(function(){

    //do something 
    });
```

You don't need if else for this problem . using jquery selector you can do that easily without if/else .

Comment: Yes it does work (I tried it on its own) but I would like to find a solution so that I can have the code working in both cases (albeit slightly differently of course :-) I'm looking for something like this; if href == pdf then do this, if href == mp3 then do that...

Comment: I am trying it out at this very moment. But when I click on pdf href, it runs the code dedicated for mp3 :-/ this is why I think an else statement would help differentite the to part...

Comment: Nihar, in my script the part of the code for mp3 comes last, so I think is overides the part for pdf. Shoud the names of the variables be changed so that there is no mixing?

Comment: Using a different variable is  good practice . make them different .

Comment: Doesn't work. Changed all variables, still mixing thing up. I believe there should be some way of separating the two snipets with some kin of 'or' statement...

Answer (score 0):

Nihar Sakhar was very close but his answer did not work.
It was also necessary to wrap the script within a function like so :

```
function somenameforthefirstcase(/* file contents go here */ })()


function somenameforthesecondcase(/* file contents go here */ })()
```

as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983151/one-javascript-script-derails-another-though-not-adressing-the-same-element-wh) by Vld.

Thanks to both.